# How to add command-line arguments support to a Quickly 12.08.1 application?

Tags: command-line, application-development, quickly

I've upgraded Quickly to 12.08.1 and it wiped command-line arguments support from `bin/project-name` along with adding

```
### DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE ###
```

But I'm using arguments for the quicklist. Therefore, subj.

Additionally, to the Quickly developers: what was the problem with main executable being changable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickly 12.08.1 did not "wipe" commandline arguments from your program. It just moved them from `bin/project_name` to `project_name/__init__.py`. There you will find the `parse_options` function, which you can edit to your liking.

Second question: I can not speak for the quickly developers, but my guess would be that it is easier to upgrade a project, if you move code that has to change in every project away from code which will probably not change.

Third point (although you did not ask...): Quickly is just a tool to help you coding. If you would like to change code inside a `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE` block, just go ahead and edit it! Nothing horrible will happen. There is no magic involved, just make sure to check (with `bzr diff` or similar) what part of your code has changed before you commit your project.